# How to use variable as the table identifier in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have this:

```
CREATE TABLE ftable (
id     INT,
fvalue VARCHAR(14)
);

INSERT INTO ftable VALUES (1,'tableB'),(2,'tableA');

CREATE TABLE tableA (
value VARCHAR(14)
);

SELECT @tmp:=fvalue FROM ftable WHERE id=2;
```

How do I make it so I can do this:

```
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('buhambug');
```

Becuase as far I know that throws a mysql error.Can someone show me a sqlfiddle of the solution? Or maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL to use a variable as an object name:

```
SET @tmp = (SELECT fvalue FROM ftable WHERE id=2);

SET @SQL = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@tmp,' VALUES (''buhambug'')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/130c4/2)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is that it show `@TMP:=FVALUE` as the returned field name instead of `value`. Why is that? After all the schema is this: CREATE TABLE tableA (
**value** VARCHAR(14)
);

Comment: Okay its because the variable @tmp in the insert statement is not actually targeting `tableA`.. If I do `SELECT * FROM ftable` it will give me the same result. So I have to conclude it did not target properly?

Comment: I think you just need to view the next record set, because you are using `SELECT` to assign the value to `@tmp` so it generates a record set. In [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/130c4/6) I have used `SET` instead of `SELECT` so now there is only one recordset which shows **Bahambug**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do in static sql.
You can do it in stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists test_call$$

create procedure test_call(table_in varchar(100))
begin
  set @q = concat("select * from ", table_in);

  PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

end$$

delimiter ;

call test_call('TeableA');

drop procedure if exists test_call;
```

In general dynamic read from dynamic tables is not a good decision